# Yii Array to string conversion

Tags: php, yii

I am getting an Error 500 Array to String conversion message which i can't seem to resolve. I get it from inserting the following line of code and also If I put the line of code in my update function it runs.

> ```
> $items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findAll('bookingId=:bookingId', array(':bookingId'=>1));
> ```

```
public function getItemsToUpdate(){
        // create an empty list of records
        $items = array();


            // Iterate over each item from the submitted form                        
            if (isset($_POST['BookingRoom']) && is_array($_POST['BookingRoom'])) {  

                foreach ($_POST['BookingRoom'] as $item) {
                    // If item id is available, read the record from database 
                    if ( array_key_exists('id', $item) ){

                        $items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findByPk($item['id']);
                    }
                    // Otherwise create a new record
                    else {

                        $items[] = new BookingRoom();
                    }
                } 
            } else {


                $items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findAll('bookingId=:bookingId', array(':bookingId'=>1));
            } 
            return $items;                     
    }
```

Update function in same Booking controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
            $items = array();
            $items=$this->getItemsToUpdate();




    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);                                                                              


            if(isset($_POST['BookingRoom']))
              {

                $valid=true;
                foreach($items as $i=>$item)
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['BookingRoom'][$i]))
                    $item->attributes=$_POST['BookingRoom'][$i];
                    $valid=$item->validate() && $valid;
                }

                $valid=$model->validate() && $valid;
                if($valid){

                }                                                                          
              }

    $this->render('update',
                    array('items'=>$items, 'model'=>$model));

}
```

Comment: That line should be `$items = ....` not `$items[] = ....`

Comment: That works now thanks. Could you explain why it wasn't working? I can't push a two-dimensional array of objects onto an existing array?

Comment: @user3784836 you can add results to an array, but you'd have to use the "+" operator. By doing `$items[] = ...`, you end up adding a single element to the array, and that element is an array itself, containing the found records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line should be `$items = ...` not `$items[] = ...`. The latter appends an element to the array. `findAll()` returns an array of models therefore the former should be used.